# Why does XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader() set undefined or null type as string?

Tags: javascript, http, web

I've found `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader()` sets `undefined` value as `"undefined"`.
For example, `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("x-custom-header", undefined)` results passing `"undefined"` string value of `x-custom-header` to server while I expect not passing `x-custom-header`. I guess this will make much chaos for frontend developers, but there's any reason for this. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: HTTP headers are text and `undefined` becomes `"undefined"` when coerced to string. For good or bad, that's how JavaScript was designed 25 years ago. Of course `XMLHttpRequest` is slightly more recent and it could have been written to handle non-string types differently but that's how it is. In any case, what'd be the use case? What exact output would you expect in order to find it more useful?